# Subtle point in the proof that each finite spanning set of a vector space contains a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I saw the following proof of the fact that each finite spanning set $S$ of a vector space $V$ has a subset $B\subseteq S$, which is a basis of $V$.

**Lemma.** *If $T$ is a minimal spanning set (i.e., $T$ is a spanning set and there is no spanning set which is a proper subset of $T$), then $T$ is a basis.*

Proof. We have to show that $T$ is linearly independent. If not, then there is an $x\in T$ such that $x$ is a linear combination of $T\setminus\{x\}$. But then $T\setminus\{x\}$ is a spanning set which is a proper subset of $T$, contradicting the minimality of $T$.

**Theorem.** *Let $S$ be a finite spanning set of $V$. Then there is a $B\subseteq S$ which is a basis of $V$.*

Proof. Consider the following algorithm: if $S$ is linearly dependent, there is an $x$ such that $x$ is a linear combination of $S\setminus \{x\}$. In this case, set $S:=S\setminus \{x\}$ and repeat this step; else, stop.

At the end of the execution of the algorithm, $S$ is still a spanning set (because we only deleted redundant vectors). Also $S$ is then a minimal spanning set, because otherwise we would have deleted more vectors. Thus, by the lemma, $S$ is a basis.

**My question:** Is it really necessary to use the lemma? Doesn't the following argument suffice: Also $S$ is linearly independent, since otherwise, the algorithm wouldn't have ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're right. If the algorithm ended, the remaining set must be linearly independent. And it must end because there are only finitely many vectors in the spanning set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user7280899 No problem.